# What does linearly equivalent mean in this context

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I'm trying to understand this proof of Fulton's [algebraic curves book](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf) page 107:

[image]

I didn't understand what does linearly equivalent mean in this context and why this implies it suffices to show that $\text{div}(\omega)=E_{n-3}+\text{div}(f_y)$.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Two divisors are linearly equivalent if they differ by a principal divisor.

Comment: yes, but why this happens in this case?